# Data integartion with ssis on Dynamics 365 script Component could not execute

Tags: sql-server, ssis

This is the exception thrown

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Copy the dll to

```
 C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>
```

And to this folder:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<version>\SDK\Assemblies\
```

Read more in this [article](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/referencing-custom-assembly-inside.html?m=1)